Is this a DDOS attack, or something else?
I am responsible for a reasonably big UK site and since last Thursday we've been getting hit with heavy usage that's killing the server for a few minutes, it's happening roughly once per hour (but varies, the intensity varies as well).
The problem is that whoever is sending these is using "google.com/url?" redirects (sometimes it's "google.co.uk/url?"). So this gives Google as the referrer and I don't know how to get better data.
We are behind Fastly, and I already have a bunch of VCL snippets blocking various crawlers but I don't know if I can block these without interfering with normal usage.
Our hosting service is Heroku (not my decision) and they had a Fastly add-on which we were using, now they are withdrawing this so last Thursday we migrated to a proper Fastly account - everything was migrated accurately.
And that's when the trouble started.

Are all the other metrics are green? What is the DNS TTL?

hm you don't happen to have an app that people install on their phone and which periodically checks for news?

so, how many requests are "too many" for you, by the way?

@MarcusMüller There's no app, but this started Thursday, the site has existed for years. Fastly handles 98% of requests but these bypass it apparently. Starts falling over at maybe 100/sec roughly, although a large site we don't expect heavy usage.

@GregAskew I don't actually have access to that.

One thing I do know is that the TLS certs were renewed by Fastly this morning and we haven't had a blip for four hours now. Maybe that was it? (So far beyond my knowledge I have no idea.)

100 per second?? that's something my raspberry pi can easily handle, or how large are these requests/what kind of computation do they require?
